# How to extract coordinated from json file in Python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, numpy

```
{
"FAM": {
    "COORDINATES": [
        [
            50,
            50
        ],
        [
            90,
            100
        ],
        [
            60,
            30
        ]
    ]
},

"radius": 10
```

}

I have json file with three different coordinates. I need to extract the coordinates and put them on a image file in form of circle.

I'm looking for some suggestion about how to extract the coordinates.
Any help will be highly appretiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

with open ('ex.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
    
#print(config)

coords = config['FAM']['COORDINATES']

print(coords)
```

This stores the coordinates in `coords` and prints them. Does this answer your question?